# redshift sum() window function behavior

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to use Redshift SUM() and window functions to perform a cumulative sum. My data looks like this:

| ID | item_date | item_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 01/01/2019 | 11 |
| 12 | 02/01/2019 | 8 |
| 12 | 03/01/2019 | 0 |
| 12 | 04/01/2019 | 5 |
| 12 | 05/01/2019 | 21 |
| 12 | 06/01/2019 | 0 |

Currently, my summation looks like this:

`SUM(item_count) over (partition by ID order by item_date rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_count`

But it produces this output:

| ID | item_date | item_count | cumulative_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 01/01/2019 | 11 | 11 |
| 12 | 02/01/2019 | 8 | 19 |
| 12 | 03/01/2019 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 04/01/2019 | 5 | 24 |
| 12 | 05/01/2019 | 21 | 45 |
| 12 | 06/01/2019 | 0 | 0 |

The behavior is correct EXCEPT when item_count = 0. Obviously my desired output would be:

| ID | item_date | item_count | cumulative_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 01/01/2019 | 11 | 11 |
| 12 | 02/01/2019 | 8 | 19 |
| 12 | 03/01/2019 | 0 | 19 |
| 12 | 04/01/2019 | 5 | 24 |
| 12 | 05/01/2019 | 21 | 45 |
| 12 | 06/01/2019 | 0 | 45 |

I've looked into using the `LAST_VALUE()` function as a way to backfill the zero-values but in redshift you can't nest window functions.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: `rows unbounded preceding` is the default behavior -- you don't need to specify it. Your code looks good; could be a bug in redshift (not surprising since it's behind the times). What's the specific version you are using?

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks for the tip - using redshift version 1.0.33426

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift is a tried and true database with years under its belt so for there to be a bug in basic functionality seems unlikely but should be checked out.  I through together this test case SQL and ran it on my cluster and it produced the expected results.

```
create table test (ID int,  item_date date, item_count int);

insert into test values 
(12, '01/01/2019', 11),
(12, '02/01/2019', 8),
(12, '03/01/2019', 0),
(12, '04/01/2019', 5),
(12, '05/01/2019', 21),
(12, '06/01/2019', 0);

select *, SUM(item_count) over (partition by ID order by item_date rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_count
from test;
```

and it produced:

```
id | item_date  | item_count | cumulative_count
---+------------+------------+-----------------
12 | 2019-01-01 |         11 |               11
12 | 2019-02-01 |          8 |               19
12 | 2019-03-01 |          0 |               19
12 | 2019-04-01 |          5 |               24
12 | 2019-05-01 |         21 |               45
12 | 2019-06-01 |          0 |               45
```

My cluster's version is Redshift 1.0.34272

Does this test code produce the correct answer on your cluster?  If it does then there is something subtle going on with your query/data/situation.  If not then I'd package it up and submit a support ticket.

====================================================

Pondering this and I had a thought on how this could have happened.  If you IDs are text and there are non-printing chars in them then they are seen as a different partition.  For example:

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (ID varchar(8),   item_date date, item_count int);

insert into test values 
('12', '01/01/2019', 11),
('12', '02/01/2019', 8),
('12    ', '03/01/2019', 0),
('12', '04/01/2019', 5),
('12', '05/01/2019', 21),
('12    ', '06/01/2019', 0);

select *, SUM(item_count) over (partition by ID order by item_date rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_count
from test
order by item_date;
```

Now this is just one way this could be happening. I'm sure there are others.

Comment: your second suggestion ended up solving it -there were hidden blanks leading/trailing some of the IDs. thanks so much!!